# Play m4a files in Java

Tags: java, m4a

I want to create a media player in Java. The mp3 support already works with the JLayer library  but which library can play m4a files?

I read about **vlcj** here on stackoverflow, but this seems to depend on Swing/AWT which I wouldn't use because I want to port the application to Android later on.

Comment: Here's a similar question.  It's not answered so I wouldn't consider it a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221191/is-there-a-good-java-sound-library-i-can-use-to-play-mpeg-4-audio-m4a-files

Comment: yeah I found that but as you said it's not answered. So I tried to ask again because it's more probable that a new question is answered than an old one

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [JAAD](http://jaadec.sourceforge.net/)? It's a Javasound SPI that decodes AAC audio, I've used it with success previously.

Note that m4a is a container format, and while it usually contains (in my experience) AAC audio, in theory it could contain other formats instead.

You can find some information about getting it working without Javasound (and a test case) [here](http://jaadec.sourceforge.net/usage.php).

Comment: I honestly don't know what an SPI is and neither how I use it. But it sounds promising. Did you use it for m4as?

Comment: It's a service provider interface - just add it to the class path and Javasound should pick up that it can support the new format. And yup, used it for m4as and worked fine.

Comment: I googled together this code, because I never used Javasound but it gives me a NegativeArraySizeException.
http://pastebin.com/Uvyy8Sr2

Comment: @user1839433 I'm not sure about that directly, but a good place to start would be the Java sound trail here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll look at it. Is there any way to check if the SPI is working? It might be the problem

Comment: @user1839433 Try playing an AAC file - if it works, then JAAD is working. Alternatively, try this (http://jaadec.sourceforge.net/usage.php) to bypass Javasound and check.

Comment: @berry120 I would suggest editing the information about the tutorial, and the test case to see if it's working, into your answer.

Comment: It says no reader associated to the extension aac. I added the jaad.jar to the build path with Eclipse

Comment: i tried jaad with an m4a aac recorded using android. jaad misreads the headers and throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is indirect.  I don't really know anything about m4a files.  But what I have found is an open source library that can stream them as a flash server named [red5](https://code.google.com/p/red5/).  It's written in Java so theoretically you should be able to browse their code to figure out how to do it.

Hopefully someone here can give a more direct answer, this is the best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Java 7 or later, you have access to the Javafx library. You can also use your media player (like iTunes or Windows Media Player) to convert to the simpler mp3 version and run that. I wouldn't recommend .wav files as they have significantly more data usage than mp3s, (which condense the file size by compressing the .wav data and omitting inaudible and otherwise garbage-y data).

```
import javafx.scene.media.*;
String name = "song.mp3";
Media song = new Media(name);
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(song);
player.play();
```